# Add colorbar to rasterio plots with facets

Tags: python, rasterio

I made some maps as a vector file over several raster, arranged in facets.
I used `rasterio`, `matplotlib` and `geopandas`.
How to plot also the colorbar at the right of each facet?

```
import rasterio as rio
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ras1 = rio.open("/path/file1.tif")
ras2 = rio.open("/path/file2.tif")
vecGpd = gpd.read_file("/path/file3.tif")

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=4, figsize=(10,10))

plot1 = rio.plot.show(source=ras1, ax=ax[0,0])
vecGpd.plot(ax=plot1)
# add here colorbar 1

plot2 = rst.plot.show(source=ras2, ax=ax[0,1])
vecGpd.plot(ax=plot2)
# add here colorbar 2
            
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

import rasterio 

from rasterio import plot

import geopandas as gpd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize']=9,4



# Read raster

b1 = rasterio.open()
b2 = rasterio.open()
b3 = rasterio.open()

ba1 = b1.read()
ba2 = b2.read()
ba3 = b3.read()

bres1 = np.reshape(ba1, (ba1.shape[0]*ba1.shape[1], ba1.shape[2]))
bres2 = np.reshape(ba2, (ba2.shape[0]*ba2.shape[1], ba2.shape[2]))
bres3 = np.reshape(ba3, (ba3.shape[0]*ba3.shape[1], ba3.shape[2]))


# Read geometry

shapefile = gpd.read_file()


# Plot raster colorbar

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2,ncols=2, figsize=(12,12))

base1 = plt.imshow(bres1)
base2 = plt.imshow(bres2)
base3 = plt.imshow(bres3)

image1  = rasterio.plot.show(b1, ax=ax[0,0], cmap='nipy_spectral', title='Band 1')
image2  = rasterio.plot.show(b2, ax=ax[0,1], cmap='nipy_spectral', title='Band 2')
image3  = rasterio.plot.show(b3, ax=ax[1,0], cmap='nipy_spectral', title='Band 3')

shapefile.plot(ax=image1, color='red')
shapefile.plot(ax=image2, color='red')
shapefile.plot(ax=image3, color='red')

fig.colorbar(base1, ax=ax[0,0])
fig.colorbar(base2, ax=ax[0,1])
fig.colorbar(base3, ax=ax[1,0])

fig.delaxes(ax=ax[1,1]) 
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much again Salim. It works

Comment: Just another question: how to delete the labels of the axis? Thanx

Comment: Public another post